# absolute positioning of divs inside parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a `header` div as the parent div of 2 divs, which is "login" and "sign up" on the left and right. I was able to correctly position the right div but the bottom of the text are not aligned with each other. Adding `left: 0 bottom: 10` and `position: absolute` to the left div makes the `header` disappear. Please help. Thanks.

```
.header {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    display:block;
    overflow:auto;
}

#left {
    font-size: 50px;
    color: white;
}

#right {
    position: absolute; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 10;
    color: white;
}
```

This is the html code

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="header">
        <div id="left">LOGIN</div>
        <div id="right">
            Don't have an account? <a href="#">sign up</a>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="testbox">
        <form action="/">
            <label id="icon" for="name"><i class="icon-envelope "></i></label> <input
                type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Email" required /> <label
                id="icon" for="name"><i class="icon-user"></i></label> <input
                type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required /> <label
                id="icon" for="name"><i class="icon-shield"></i></label> <input
                type="password" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Password"
                required />
            <div class="gender">
                <input type="radio" value="None" id="male" name="gender" checked />
                <label for="male" class="radio" chec>Male</label> <input
                    type="radio" value="None" id="female" name="gender" /> <label
                    for="female" class="radio">Female</label>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="button">Register</a>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bottom: 10px; instead of bottom: 10

Comment: can you prepare a js fiddle?

Comment: Thank you all for your help! had to accept the first one though. :)

Comment: opps sorry, there's something I am missing, your answers on fiddle is working but when I updated my code, its not aligned, maybe something else affecting the alignment? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you have put `bottom:10` use css based units like "em","px",etc.

Also, Sometimes "bottom" only works if you have a implicit height defined to parent element(in this case header)

```
.header {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    display:block;
    overflow:auto;
    height:100px;/* or any height you like, if not specified then bottom:xpx will not work in some cases */
}
```

Here is a Pen that i have made to demonstrate the same.
http://codepen.io/Prashantsani/pen/yriHa

Comment: `Sometimes "bottom" only works if you have a implicit height defined to parent element(in this case header)` - Wrong, `bottom` is position attribute and will always work if you have defined `position` for that element!

Comment: Sorry I meant if the height is not defined if all are absolutely positioned elements. http://codepen.io/Prashantsani/pen/GjJcr

Answer (score 0):

One of the alternatives is using `float`.

**DEMO: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dreamonic/cu5n4ou5/1/)**

HTML for the header:

```
<div class="header">
    <div id="left">LOGIN</div>
    <div id="right">Don't have an account? <a href="#">sign up</a></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    display:block;
    overflow:auto;
}
#left {
    font-size: 50px;
    float: left;
}
#right {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Your answer too is working on fiddle but its not working on my code.

Comment: You can look in the browsers' developer console to see the applied CSS of an element. Have a look at your code, and try to figure out what is preventing it from working properly :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
#left {
    font-size: 50px;
    color: black;
    float:left;
}

#right {
    position: absolute; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 10;
    color: black;
    margin-top: 30px;
    float:left;
}
.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}
```

Above CSS is working fine for me. Check it out here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1fvzubej/1/)

Comment: The *bottom* of both texts in the header should align.

Comment: opps sorry, there's something I am missing, your answers on fiddle is working but when I updated my code, its not aligned, maybe something else affecting the alignment? :(

Comment: @fyethfyeth This should works. Forgot to mention the .clearFix css in my answers. Now, I have updated.try this out.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong css value. You should use `bottom:10px;` and not `bottom:10;`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uqx2dp61/)**

```
.header {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    display:block;
    overflow:auto;
}

#left {
    font-size: 50px;
    color: white;
}

#right {
    position: absolute; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 10px;
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give the value in pixel,

```
#right {
    position: absolute; 
    bottom:20px;
    right:0;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hvsb7sun/)